# How to determine how many elements in $R / I$ where $R$ is ring of quadratic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This might be a very basic question for some of you. Indeed in $\textbf Z$, it's very easy. For example, $\textbf Z / \langle 2 \rangle$ consists of $\langle 2 \rangle$ and $\langle 2 \rangle + 1$. Obviously just two elements. In general, if $p$ is a positive prime in $\textbf Z$, then $\textbf Z / \langle p \rangle$ consists of one principal ideal and $p - 1$ cosets.

I guess it's also easy in imaginary quadratic integer rings, since we can visualize them in the complex plane, e.g., $\textbf Z[i] / \langle 1 + i \rangle$ consists of $\langle 1 + i \rangle$, $\langle 1 + i \rangle + 1$ and $\langle 1 + i \rangle + i$... wait a minute, three elements? I'm not sure that's quite right.

And I really have no idea how to go about, say, $\textbf Z[\sqrt{14}] / \langle 4 + \sqrt{14} \rangle$. To say nothing of something like $\textbf Z[\sqrt{10}] / \langle 2, \sqrt{10} \rangle$.

Given a ring $R$ of algebraic integers of degree $2$, and a prime ideal $\mathfrak P$, how do you determine how many elements there are in $R / \mathfrak P$?

Comment: Pick an isomorphism of abelian groups $\varphi : \mathbf{Z}[i] \to \mathbf{Z}^2$. Then $\varphi((1+i) \mathbf{Z}[i]) = A \mathbf{Z}^2$ where $A$ is the matrix of the multiplication by $1+i$. And (as abelian groups) $\mathbf{Z}[i] /(1+i) \mathbf{Z}[i]\cong \varphi(\mathbf{Z}[i]) /\varphi((1+i) \mathbf{Z}[i]) =\mathbf{Z}^2/A\mathbf{Z}^2$, the latter having $|\det(A)|$ elements (by the LU decomposition of $A$, or its Smith normal form, or...). Note how $\det(A)$ is indeed the definition of the field norm $N_{\mathbf{Q}[i]/\mathbf{Q}}(1+i)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For principal ideals, it's easy: if $L$ is a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal O_L$, and if $(a)$ is an ideal in $\mathcal O_L$, then the number of elements in $\mathcal O_L / (a)$ is $|N_{L / \mathbb Q} (a)|$, where $N_{L / \mathbb Q}(a)$ denotes the norm of the element $a$.

For a quadratic number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$, the norm of an element $x + y \sqrt{d}$ is simply $x^2 - dy^2$.

So the number of elements in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{14}] / (4 + \sqrt{14})$ is $| 4^2 - 14 \times 1^2 | = 2$.

Similarly, the number of elements in $\mathbb Z[i] / (1 + i)$ is $|1^2 + 1 \times 1^2 | = 2$. (You double counted: $1 + (1 + i)$ and $i + (1 + i)$ are the same thing, since $1 - i \in (1 + i)$ by virtue of the fact that $-i(1 + i) = 1 - i$.)

---

As for your final example, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}] / (2, \sqrt{10})$, it might be easier to use an integral basis.

It is well known that $\{ 1, \sqrt{10} \}$ is an integral basis for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$, which is to say that every element in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$ can be  written in the form $a + b\sqrt{10}$ for a unique choice of $a, b \in \mathbb Z$. Therefore, the elements in $(2, \sqrt{10})$ are precisely the elements of the form

$$ (u + v\sqrt{10})\times 2 +(w + z\sqrt{10})\times \sqrt{10} = (2u + 10z) + (2v + w) \sqrt{10}$$
where $u, v, w, z \in \mathbb Z$. And if you think about it, this includes precisely those elements $a + b \sqrt{10}$ in $ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$ where $a$ is *even*. Hence $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}] / (2, \sqrt{10})$ contains two cosets: $(2, \sqrt{10})$ and $1 + (2, \sqrt{10})$.

I hope these examples provide you with enough techniques to be getting on with....

Answer (score 4):

$$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{14}]/(4+\sqrt{14}) = \Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-14,X+4) = \Bbb Z[X]/(2,X+4) = \Bbb Z[X]/(2,X) = \Bbb F_2$$

$$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{10}]/(2,\sqrt{10}) = \Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-10, 2, X) = \Bbb Z[X]/(2, X) = \Bbb F_2$$

The trick is to move the situation to computing ideals in $\Bbb Z[X]$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid  there is no general approach if not going through the ring of integers of the number field. Recall that for a number field $K$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbf Q$, the norm $N(x)$ of an element $x\in K^*$ is defined as the product $s_1(x)...s_n(x)$, where the $s_i$ are the $n$ distinct embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbf C$. If $x$ is a non zero element of the ring of integers $R$ of $K$, it is known that $\mid N(x)\mid $ is finite, equal to card $(R/Rx)$. This is easily shown by using the fact that $R$ is a free $\mathbf Z$-module of rank $n$ and, because $\mathbf Z$ is a PID, there exists a $\mathbf Z$-basis $(e_1 ,..., e_n)$ of $R$ and elements $c_j$ of $\mathbf Z$ s.t. $(c_1 e_1,..., c_n e_n)$ is a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $Rx$. Thus, to get card $(R/Rx)$, it suffices to compute $N(x)$, which is, up to a sign, the constant term of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbf Q$. *Warning* : if $K=\mathbf Q (x)$, then $\mathbf Z [x]$ is contained in, but not necessarily equal to $R$. However the discrepancy between these two rings can be dealt with when knowing enough parameters attached to $K$ such as the discriminant, etc. See e.g. the examples of quadratic and cubic fields given in Marcus' book "Number Fields", chap. 2. But there is *no general systematic* approach. **Your example**: $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 14), x= 4+\sqrt 14, N(x)=2$. Here $R=\mathbf Z(\sqrt 14)$ because $14\equiv 2$ mod $4$, so card $\mathbf Z[\sqrt 14]/(\sqrt 14)=2$.

More generally, for a non zero ideal $I$ of $R$, the norm $N(I)$ can be *defined* as card $(R/I)$, but then, we must give an independent way to compute this cardinal. This is done by using the fact that $R$ is a Dedekind ring, in which any non zero $I$ can be be written uniquely as a product $I={P_1}^{m_1}...{P_r}^{m_r}$ of powers of prime ideals of $R$ (or maximal ideals, it's the same thing here). By the CRT, we are reduced to compute card $(R/P^m)$. For this, consider the chain of ideals $P^m<P^{m-1}<...<P<R$, in which two consecutive terms are of the form $J<PJ$, hence without any ideal strictly squeezed between them. It follows that, denoting by $p$ be the prime of $\mathbf Z$ under $P$ and by $f_P$ the inertia index of $P$, the quotient $PJ/P$ can be viewed as a $1$-dimensional vector space over $R/P$, hence a vector space of dimension $f_P$ over $\mathbf F_p$ . In other words, $[R/P^m : R/P]=mf_P$, i.e. card $(R/P^m)=p^{mf_P}$. **Your example**: $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 10), I=(2,\sqrt 10)$. Here $R=\mathbf Z[\sqrt 10]$, again because $10\equiv 2$ mod $4$. You could factorize $I$ and apply the above result, but it's quicker to consider the isomorphism of *additive groups* $R/I\cong (R/\mathbf Z\sqrt 10)/ (I/\mathbf Z \sqrt 10)\cong\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ (check).